# Magento 2.4.3 - Grouped/bundle product out of stock when one or more child items is out of stock

Tags: products, stock, magento2.4.3

How can I make grouped/bundle products out of stock if one or more child products are out of stock?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this for **Grouped products**. What you want to do is update the stock table.

Add this to your module's `etc/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\InventoryGroupedProductIndexer\Indexer\SelectBuilder">
        <plugin name="namespace_grouped_product_stock_is_salable_logic" type="NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\InventoryGroupedProductIndexer\Indexer\SelectBuilderAfterPlugin" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

And this is your class:

```
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace NameSpace\ModuleName\Plugin\InventoryGroupedProductIndexer\Indexer;

use Magento\Framework\DB\Select;
use Magento\InventoryGroupedProductIndexer\Indexer\SelectBuilder;

class SelectBuilderAfterPlugin
{
    /**
     * @param SelectBuilder $subject
     * @param Select $return
     * @param int $stockId
     * @return Select
     * @throws \Zend_Db_Select_Exception
     */
    public function afterExecute(SelectBuilder $subject, Select $return, int $stockId): Select
    {
        $columns = $return->getPart(Select::COLUMNS);
        if (is_array($columns) && count($columns)) {
            foreach ($columns as &$columnEntry) {
                list($correlationName, $column, $alias) = $columnEntry;

                if ($correlationName == 'child_stock' && $column instanceof \Zend_Db_Expr) {
                    $expressionString = str_replace(["SUM", "MAX"], "MIN", $column->__toString());
                    $column = new \Zend_Db_Expr($expressionString);
                    $columnEntry = [$correlationName, $column, $alias];
                }
            }
            $return->setPart(Select::COLUMNS, $columns);
        }
        return $return;
    }
}
```

**For Bundled Products,**
I haven't done it but if you make every option as required then I believe it will not allow to sell if any of the required option goes out of stock.